# Logout clear SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, logout

I have a login page that saves `username` and `password` to `SharedPreferences`. I have another `Activity` class that includes a logout button. I want to clear `SharedPreferences` when I click the logout button. The problem is that I don't get the `SharedPreferences` from this class. How can I get the `SharedPreferences`?

LoginPage

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    public  SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private Boolean saveLogin;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_Login);

         loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
         loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

         saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);

         if (saveLogin == true) {
                name.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
                pass.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));   
            }

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 name1 = name.getText().toString();
                 pass1 = pass.getText().toString();
               //new Thread (new Task()).start();
                    loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", name1);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", pass1);
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                 new myAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        });
}
```

Logout Button in AnotherActivity

```
 logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching News Feed Screen

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you want to clear the preferences on log out, **why** do you store them on log in?

Comment: post ur code i'll give u solution within a 5 minites..

Comment: i suggest you to check you code when you save or retrieve using shared preferences, because shared preferences are accessible in all the activities.

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.clear();
              editor.commit();
paste this code in logout onclicklistener

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this !

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Launching News Feed Screen

             SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.clear();
             editor.apply();
             finish();
 });
```

Comment: Any idea of how to do similar for DataStore Preferences ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a trouble in understanding Shared preferences in android .

According to official documentation

> To get a SharedPreferences object for your application, use one of two
> methods:
>
> getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences
> files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.
>
> getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for
> your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your
> Activity, you don't supply a name.

You should have a Context for using both the above methods .

Also Shared preferences are stored asa key value pair , so clearing should mean that you set the values to some empty string.

For more details , and better explanation you can read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Hope this will help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It as Simple. Like you save your data in `SharedPrefernce`

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MYKEY",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("username" , username);
editor.putString("password" , password);
```

Now you can retrieve as in any class of your app like,

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MYKEY",0);
String uname = sp.getString("username");
String pwd = sp.getString("password");
```

And for clear your username and password

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

or

```
editor.remove("username");
editor.remove("password");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a SharedPreference utility class. This can be accessed from both the activities.

Comment: I didn't give the downvote but likely it's because your answer isn't descriptive at all. Provide more details about what your "SharedPreference utility class" is and how it works. Maybe give some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can use this code to clear the sharedpreference data

```
private val sharedPref = "sharedpreference"

val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.clear()
            editor.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preferences =getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.clear();
             editor.apply();
             finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin :

```
fun clearall(context:Context){
      val  sp :SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor=sp.edit()
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()
        editor.commit()
    }
```

This work for me